# how can i pass a struct inside a linked list?

Tags: struct, linked-list

I'm new to c language,
I always find this site very helpful but could not find a clear answer to this problem.

im having a hard time to send a struct with 3 fileds as a linked list value.

this is the function:

```
void add_to_list(list *s,  find_indexs * q)
 {
    list_node* ln = (list_node*)malloc(sizeof(list_node));
    ln->p = (find_indexs*)malloc(sizeof(find_indexs));
    ln->p->index_i= q->index_i;
    ln->p->index_j = q->index_j;
    ln->p->value = q->value;
    ln->next =s->head;
    s->head = ln;
    s->size++;
 }
```

now inside the `function ln->?=(the wanted filed)`
but after that im getiing a `nullptr` warning.

in adittion if someone can explain to me how to declare s at main,how to send and recive in function that would be very helpfull!

thank u very much,have a good day!